# I want to apply a style request to all sheets in a spreadsheet using google spreadsheet API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

the following is a batch updates request, it is styling only the sheet of index 0, I would like to apply this style to all sheets in the spreadsheet, or alternatively style each sheet by name...
I am trying to avoid making a request, getting the sheet ids and names, and styling each one by its id.

````
   // start sheet formatting for better readability/visuals
           $formatRowColrequests = [
               new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                   'updateSheetProperties' => [
                       'properties' => [
                           'gridProperties' => [
                               'frozenRowCount' => 1
                           ]
                       ],
                       'fields' => 'gridProperties.frozenRowCount'
                   ]
               ]),
               // columns auto width to fit content
               new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                   "autoResizeDimensions" => [
                       "dimensions" => [
                           "dimension" => "COLUMNS",
                           "startIndex" => 0,
                       ]
                   ]
               ]),
               new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                   "repeatCell" => [
                       "range" => [
                           "endRowIndex" => 1,
                       ],
                       "cell" => [
                           "userEnteredFormat" => [
                               "backgroundColor" => [
                                   "red" => 152 / 255,
                                   "green" => 217 / 255,
                                   "blue" => 99 / 255,
                                   "alpha" => 0.8
                               ],
                               "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
                               "textFormat" => [
                                   "fontSize" => 12,
                                   "bold" => true,
                               ]
                           ]
                       ],
                       "fields" => "userEnteredFormat(textFormat,backgroundColor,horizontalAlignment)"
                   ]
               ]),
               new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                   "repeatCell" => [
                       "range" => [
                           "startRowIndex" => 1,
                       ],
                       "cell" => [
                           "userEnteredFormat" => [
                               "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
                               "textFormat" => [
                                   "fontSize" => 10,
                                   "bold" => false
                               ]
                           ]
                       ],
                       "fields" => "userEnteredFormat(textFormat,backgroundColor,horizontalAlignment)"
                   ],
               ]),
           ];
           $batchUpdateCellFormatRequest = new \Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
               'requests' => $formatRowColrequests,
           ]);
           $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($target_spreadID, $batchUpdateCellFormatRequest);
           // end sheet formatting
   ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use your request body for all sheets or the specific sheets using the sheet names.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- You have already been able to get and put values to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, first, the sheet IDs are retrieved using the sheet names. Using these sheet IDs, your request body is used for the specification sheets.

#### Modified script:

```js
$target_spreadID = "###"; // please set Spreadsheet ID.

// Retrieve sheet IDs.
$sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use the request body.
$res = $service->spreadsheets->get($target_spreadID, [
  "ranges" => $sheetNames,
  "fields" => "sheets(properties(sheetId))",
]);

// Create request body.
$sheets = $res->getSheets();
$requests = [];
foreach ($sheets as $i => $sheet) {
  $sheetId = $sheet->getProperties()->getSheetId();
  $formatRowColrequests = [
    new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
      "updateSheetProperties" => [
        "properties" => [
          "gridProperties" => [
            "frozenRowCount" => 1,
          ],
          "sheetId" => $sheetId,
        ],
        "fields" => "gridProperties.frozenRowCount",
      ],
    ]),
    // columns auto width to fit content
    new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
      "autoResizeDimensions" => [
        "dimensions" => [
          "dimension" => "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex" => 0,
          "sheetId" => $sheetId,
        ],
      ],
    ]),
    new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
      "repeatCell" => [
        "range" => [
          "endRowIndex" => 1,
          "sheetId" => $sheetId,
        ],
        "cell" => [
          "userEnteredFormat" => [
            "backgroundColor" => [
              "red" => 152 / 255,
              "green" => 217 / 255,
              "blue" => 99 / 255,
              "alpha" => 0.8,
            ],
            "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
            "textFormat" => [
              "fontSize" => 12,
              "bold" => true,
            ],
          ],
        ],
        "fields" =>
          "userEnteredFormat(textFormat,backgroundColor,horizontalAlignment)",
      ],
    ]),
    new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
      "repeatCell" => [
        "range" => [
          "startRowIndex" => 1,
          "sheetId" => $sheetId,
        ],
        "cell" => [
          "userEnteredFormat" => [
            "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
            "textFormat" => [
              "fontSize" => 10,
              "bold" => false,
            ],
          ],
        ],
        "fields" =>
          "userEnteredFormat(textFormat,backgroundColor,horizontalAlignment)",
      ],
    ]),
  ];

  $requests = array_merge($requests, $formatRowColrequests);
}
$batchUpdateCellFormatRequest = new \Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(["requests" => $requests]);

// Request Sheets API using the created request body.
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($target_spreadID, $batchUpdateCellFormatRequest);
```

- When this script is run, your request body is used for the specific sheets declared by `$sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3"];`.
- If you want to use your request body to all sheets in the Spreadsheet, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      $sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use the request body.
      $res = $service->spreadsheets->get($target_spreadID, [
        "ranges" => $sheetNames,
        "fields" => "sheets(properties(sheetId))",
      ]);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      $res = $service->spreadsheets->get($target_spreadID, [
        "fields" => "sheets(properties(sheetId))",
      ]);
    ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Tanaike, I was trying to avoid a second request to target specific Ids as the whole spreadsheet is being manipulated by the code. I was hoping there would be a wildcard of some sort to apply a request to all sheets.

Comment: @Hsein Bitar Thank you for replying. About `I was hoping there would be a wildcard of some sort to apply a request to all sheets.`, unfortunately, in order to reflect your request body to all sheets, it is required to use the sheet ID for each sheet. I apologize for this current specification on the Google side. And, I deeply apologize my answer was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I think that my answer might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave my answer. If you are required to delete my answer, please tell me.

Comment: I did end up using the sheet ID, and your answer is useful definitely @Tanaike.
I will not mark it as accepted yet, maybe someone would find a wildcard, maybe in some updates later.

Comment: @Hsein Bitar Thank you for replying. About `I will not mark it as accepted yet, maybe someone would find a wildcard, maybe in some updates later.`, I understand your intention. I thought that unfortunately, in the current stage, this your goal cannot be achieved. So, as the current solution, I proposed the above sample script. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I would like to study more. But, I think that your goal might be achieved in the future update at the Google side.